# Fast way to check if file is open on OS X

Tags: macos, file-io

Is there a fast way to check if a file handle is closed from the command line on os x?

`lsof` works, of course, but is super slow.

Comment: If you know the filepath you can give it directly to lsof. That speeds it up quite a bit.

Comment: Even if you give it a file path it's still ridiculously slow - at least on my Mac OS 10.14.6

Answer (score 4):

You´ll probably want to check out the DTrace Family `man dtrace`.

If you´re only interested on pure "file actions" you should have a look at `opensnoop`, which builds on DTrace and has been included since Mac OS X 10.6.
You can show all file in use by a process (by -p pid or -n name) and watch files with -f /path/to/file .